# How to reuse identical properties on .NET class

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, refactoring

I have the following code. A class that will hold a fund

```
Public Class FundElement
    Public Name As New FundDetail
    Public Price As New FundDetail
    Public Code As New CodeDetail
End Class
```

A base class for each individual data field

```
Public Class FundDetail
    Protected _value As String

    Public Property value As String
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get

        Set(valueToAssign As String)
            If isValid(valueToAssign) Then
                _value = valueToAssign
            Else
                Throw New ArgumentException
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Shared Function isValid(detail As String) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

And some inherited classes that will hold logic specific to certain fields. This is the reason I wanted a class for rather than just a string for each field.

```
Public Class CodeDetail
    Inherits FundDetail

    Public Shared Shadows Function isValid(value As String) As Boolean
        Dim intPattern As Regex = New Regex("[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{12}")
        Return intPattern.IsMatch(value)
    End Function
End Class
```

Now, my problem is that the API for my class is as follows

```
Dim fund as new FundElement

FundElement.Name.Value = "Google Inc"
FundElement.Code.Value = "USD451234151234"
```

Which means that coders have access to the NAV element, which I want to hide completely. And the API is more verbose than it needs to be. I want the interface to be as follows

```
FundElement.Name = "Google Inc"
FundElement.Price = "USD451234151234"
```

I can implement this by changing the class so that each fundDetail instance is private, and by adding a new property as follows

```
Public Class FundElement

    Private _Name As New FundDetail
    Public Property Name As String
        Set(valueToAssign As String)
            _Name.value = valueToAssign
        End Set
        Get
            Return _Name.value
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _Code As New FundDetails
    Public Property _Code As String
        Set(valueToAssign As String)
            _Code.value = valueToAssign
        End Set
        Get
            Return _Code.value
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _Price As New PriceDetail
    Public Property _Price As String
        Set(valueToAssign As String)
            _Price.value = valueToAssign
        End Set
        Get
            Return _Price.value
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Now this ended up very verbose for just 3 members. Additionally, the code for each property was almost exactly the same. It's tedious to type and cluttery to read.

Is there any way I can achieve this without having to type the properties every time I want to add a new member?

Comment: Why would value always be a string?  Regex to test for numeric

Comment: Why are you shadowing your method? Wouldn't it be better to mark the original method `Overridable` and in the inherited method mark it `Overrides`?

Comment: Because overridable functions cannot be shared.

Comment: I am sorry but your code in current form is not workable. `Shared Shadows`... REALLY? Lets just say - you don't need all these classes. A single class `Fund` would be sufficient.

Comment: Have you considered using a `BitArray` instead of a `String` as your default type for your properties? Imagine if wanted a property to store and image or a word document, then `BitArray` is more flexible than `String`. Just ignore the extra work a user of your class would need to do to store a `Decimal` - the extra flexibility would be worth it, right?

Comment: (Just in case your were unsure - that was a joke. Using `String` for every property is a bad idea.)

Comment: @T.S. If there could only be one class, that would be neat. I'd appreciate an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Why would value always be string?
I am better at C#

```
Public Class FundElement
{
    Public String Name   { get; set; }
    Public Decimal Price { get; set; } 
    Public Int32 Shares  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Values should always be read as strings. The user should be able to do Fund.Shares = "243.45" , rather than force him to do Fund.Shares = toInt32("243.45")
Additionally, many of the checks I need to implement, will be implemented on strings, like checking if a string has 12 numeric characters and 3letters at the start.

Comment: Values should not always be read as string.   Regex "^\d*$" is not going allow  243.45.   You could use decimal.   You asked how to simplify the code and showed you.

Comment: I mean that the source files are always going to be strings. So if they are going to be stored as strings a conversion must take place somewhere.
Additionally this is the simplest of validity checks I am looking for. I will replace the example regex for one that cannot be replaced by native data types.

Comment: Then deal with it in the data loader.  You asked you to simplify code and you just want to make things difficult.

Comment: The idea of these classes are to contain the conversion logic in one place instead of repeating it every time new data is loaded. Sure, In this case this regex matches the logic of ToInt32, but for the greatest part, I need to handle the validity checks myself.
In the case of Shares, if the input string is "435 M" I want it to be considered valid, because it probably represents 435 million.

Comment: That is whole lot of detail not in the question.  Even with the detail I don't like your approach but tired of trying to help you.

Comment: If you change your mind let me know how you would do it.